# Navigating between Kendo Pages by using ID and showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have 2 views in my MVC project From the View1 I am taking an ID and passing it to View2. On view2, I already have KendoGrid and I have controller that reads all data for me and display in grid.

My question is how to get data from ID in View2? I copied my script code of View2 below

```
            var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:23355/",
                dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type: "GET",
                            url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/api/SpecificationDetails",
                            dataType: "json",
                            cache: false
                        },
                        update: {


                           // update code goes here
                            },

                        },

                        destroy: {
                            // delete code goes here

                          },
                            create: {
                               // create code goes here
                            },

                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                console.log(operation + '-' + options.models);
                                if (operation === "create" && options.models) {
                                    options.models[0].SpexHeaderId = 5;
                                    var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(options.models[0])
                                    console.log(jsonstr);
                                    return jsonstr;
                                }



                                else if (operation === "update" && options.models) {
                                    var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(options.models[0])
                                    console.log(jsonstr);
                                    return jsonstr;
                                }
                                else if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                }


                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 4,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "SpecificationDetailId",
                                fields: {
                                    SpecificationDetailId: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                                    DescriptionTitle: "DescriptionTitle",
                                    Description: "Description",
                                }
                            },
                            total: function (response) {
                                return response.total;
                            }
                        }

                });
```

Comment: You need to include `jQuery` on the page (*before* you reference `$(document).ready()`).

Comment: Because you have not included `jquery-{version}.js` (or your scripts are in the wrong order)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Problem solved by this

Answer (score 1):

You are running jQuery 1.5.

Kendo UI requires a **minimum** of jQuery 1.7.1 (for [**Kendo UI 2011.3.1129**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/backwards-compatibility/2012-backward-compatibility#changes-from-2011-q3-sp1-201131407)). The current official version of Kendo UI (**[2017.2.504 (R2 2017)](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r2-2017)**) requires jQuery 1.12.3.

Please refer to **[this chart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites)** for the specific version of jQuery that you require for your version of Kendo UI. You can grab a link to any version of jQuery from **[code.jquery.com](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)**.

If you are using legacy code, you'll additionally need to include **[jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)**.

Hope this helps! :)